# How to cache multithreaded API calls in java with okhttp?

Tags: java, caching, okhttp

I have multiple threads calling the same api with different params. I want to cache it. Using the cache in okhttp leads to the following error.

```
java.io.IOException: failed to rename C:\Regression360\jiracache\journal to C:\Regression360\jiracache\journal.bkp
```

I believe its a known bug in okhttp.

My code for the client is

```
private int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; 
private String cacheFileName = "C:\\Regression360";
\*not relevant parts skipped\*
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
             .cache(cache)
             .addNetworkInterceptor(provideCacheInterceptor())
             .sslSocketFactory(trustAllSslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0])
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true).connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec)).build();

Interceptor provideCacheInterceptor () {
        return new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept (Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Response response = chain.proceed( chain.request() );
                CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl.Builder()
                        .maxAge( 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES )
                        .build();
                return response.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl.toString() )
                        .build();
            }
        };
    }
```

Is there anything I am missing here? Is it possible to cache multithreaded calls?

Comment: Are you sure it´s not a file permission problem?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, the caching works without multithreading.

Comment: So it´s most likely a problem where one thread has a handle of the file while another thread wants to rename it. In this case you should use a read-write lock on the cache file.

Comment: I figured so. Is that possible in okhttp?